# Is it possible to access a private vimeo video with your API?

Tags: node.js, vimeo

I have an app and I want to integrate vimeo videos, so instead of using access domain release I would have to use the token, I read all your documentation and even then it was not clear how this request would be, I'm testing with insomnia, and it always returns an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access private videos, but you must use an access token authenticated to your user and it must have the `private` scope.

You can view documentation for this here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/guides/start#generate-access-token

To view all of your user's videos, you use `GET https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos` with a header `Authorization: bearer <token>`, to view a specific video, you use `GET https://api.vimeo.com/videos/{video_id}` with the same header.

Comment: Oh! Thank you! it worked it returns the JSON of the private video, but to access it and be able to view it in the iframe will I really have to authenticate?

Comment: You can view the different privacies here:

https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/224817847-Manage-your-video-s-privacy-settings

The short answer is yes, that's what 'private' does, but a different privacy may be what you're looking for to have it available in an iframe.